# Android SQLite take the first element from database column

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on a project and created a database with SQLite. In my database I have just two columns, column names are r_id and m_id. I want to take the first element of the r_id and assign it in to a string. The elements of the r_id column is like 1, 2, 3.. in this situation my String has to be 1.

My code; creating a db query:
There is no problem I can add data correcly.

```
my_table = "CREATE TABLE "my_table"("r_id" Text, "m_id" Text);";
db.execSQL(my_table );
```

Code to take the first element of the column;

```
public String getSetting() {
            String result = "";
            String[] columns = {"r_id"};
            String[] selectionArgs = {"1"};
            String LIMIT = String.valueOf(1); // <-- number of results we want/expect

            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.query(true, "r_id", columns, "row", selectionArgs, null, null, null, LIMIT);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                result = result + c.getString(0);
            } else {
                result = result + "result not found";
            }

            c.close();
            databaseHelper.close();
            return result;
        }
```

The error I am getting:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: row (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT r_id FROM my_table WHERE row LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4th argument of `query()` is the `WHERE` clause of the query (without the keyword `WHERE`) and for it you pass `"row"`. 
Also, the 2nd argument is the table's name for which you pass `"r_id"`, but the error message does not contain `...FROM r_id...` (although it should), so I guess that the code you posted is not your actual code.

So your query (translated in SQL) is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r_id FROM my_table WHERE row LIMIT 1
```

which is invalid.
But you don't need a `WHERE` clause if you want just the min value of the column `r_id`. 
You can do it with a query like:

```
SELECT MIN(r_id) AS r_id FROM my_table
```

without `DISTINCT` and a `WHERE` clause.

Or:

```
SELECT r_id FROM my_table ORDER BY r_id LIMIT 1;
```

So your java code should be:

```
public String getSetting() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(r_id) AS r_id FROM my_table", null);
    String result = c.moveToFirst() ? c.getString(0) : "result not found";
    c.close();
    databaseHelper.close();
    return result;
}
```

I used `rawQuery()` here instead of `query()`.

Or:

```
public String getSetting() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(false, "my_table", new String[] {"r_id"}, null, null, null, null, "r_id", "1");
    String result = c.moveToFirst() ? c.getString(0) : "result not found";
    c.close();
    databaseHelper.close();
    return result;
}
```